# Yii framework: DAO and getting element of array (model) like from object

Tags: arrays, activerecord, yii, frameworks, dao

I have Post model. When I was using AR like this:

**Controller:**

```
public function view($id)
{
   $post = Post::model->find("id=$id");
   $this->render('view', array('post'=>$post))
}
```

**View:**

```
echo $this->title
```

But when i started using DAO to improve performance of application, I got error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

The problem is I am using '->' instead of '[]'. I want change active records to DAO, so I would have change many views.

What is the way to get element using '->' without much work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think:

```
$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($q);
$cmd->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Page');
$model = $cmd->queryRow();
// $model->title
```

Also

what are you using now as your code though? Also how you use find is not ideal. should be

```
find('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show your code for DOA. However, DAO commands return arrays. They do not return objects. So when you do

```
echo $this->title
```

You are trying to get the title from something that is not an object (but probably an array; or undefined)...

The [definitive guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) shows examples of how to use DOA